# Using if condition in the Select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to use the if condition in the select query of the Oracle database. The columns should be set to some value depending on the value like the below is what I tried

```
Select if(expvalue.DATA = '0','Unpublished','Published') as STATUS from
```

DATA field is a Boolean so I want to set the Status to be Unpublished if the Boolean is 0 and published if it is 1.But the above syntax gives error like

`ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement :

```
select case when expvalue.DATA = '0' THEN 'Unpublished' ELSE 'Published' END AS STATUS from...
```